# Writing the path to a file (Path of the Folder which contains the File)

Tags: java, file, list

I am new to Java and have been trying to implement a function which creates Directories and its respective files. One of the File is "mapping.txt" which is inside a Folder named NodeA. The contents of mapping.txt is the absolute path of NodeA.

Please find the Code below, that I have tried. I have commented in all possible places for better understanding. I want to know the reason why am I not able to write in the File. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
//--------------------------   To create Node and their respective Files   ------------------------------------------------------
        for(int j=0;j<alpha.length;j++){                    //alpha is a String array which contains {"A","B","C","D"}
            node_directory=Node.concat(alpha[j]);           // nodde_directory is "C:\Users\Desktop\Node. I concat A,B,C and D to create different directories.
            File dir = new File(node_directory);
        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdirs();
       }
        System.out.println("Path: \n" +dir.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println();

        List<String> fileList = Arrays.asList(files);       // files is an array of string containing "mapping" and "data".
        Iterator <String> iter = fileList.iterator();       //I traverse through the list.
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            File next_file = new File(node_directory+"\\"+iter.next()+".txt");  //while traversing, I append the current "iter.next" to "node_directory" and append ".txt" to create files.
            System.out.println("The Files are: \n" +next_file);
            System.out.println();

            // I created the Directories, mapping and data Files for each directory. 

            /*I am stuck here, as it is not writing the path in the mapping File */

            if(iter.next()=="mapping"){         // I check if iter.next is mapping, so that i can write in the mapping file, the path of Folder containing mapping file. 
                BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(next_file));
                br.write(next_file.getAbsolutePath());
            }


    if(!next_file.exists()){
                System.out.println(next_file.createNewFile());
         }
```

I realized what is happening. Since I am traversing through the Array of String through list. The problem occurs here:

```
next_file = new File(node_directory+"\\"+iter.next()+".txt"); // This line creates files by appending the required data. Since iter.next() returns all the Files in one go, 

BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(next_file));
                br.write(dir.getAbsolutePath());
```

next_file has all the files created at once. I need to know how can I check each file after being created, so that I can edit the file.

Thank you.

Comment: How does the outcome differ from what you expect ?

Comment: I tried to the above method and it still doesn't write. The file is empty. I tried to change the project and try and yet the same result.

Comment: Tip:  Add @AdrianJandl (or whoever - the `@` is important) to ensure they are *notified* of a new comment.

Comment: @AdrianJandl Sure. I will follow

Comment: @AdrianJandl I debug the code. when I am comparing, {iter.next()=="mapping"} I tried to print the contents of iter.next() and it turns out that it is the complete Array of Strings which is "mapping" and "data". But I want to traverse and check first for "mapping" and then for "data". Now, I don't know how to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

```
if(iter.next().equals("mapping")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, assign `iter.next()` to a local variable:

```
String fileName= iter.next();
```

Because the next time you call it, the iterator jumps to the next value, and you might get `NoSuchElementException` and for sure the wrong result. Then, use this `fileName` variable in the rest of the code.

Another mistake is comparing String with `==`. String is an immutable object and by using `==` you are just comparing the object references, and not the objects. So, two completely same strings might produce false when comparing with `==`. `.equalsTo()` instead:

```
if (fileName.equals("mapping"))
```

Comment: I tried to compare with equals() and it doesn't work. Everything looks fine, with creating files and directories, except to entering the data.

Comment: Debug it, see that the two strings REALLY are the same. equals MUST work in that case. Hope you're using an IDE (e.g. Eclipse)

Comment: Yup. I am using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: I debugged it. when I am comparing, 
          {iter.next()=="mapping"}

I tried to print the contents of iter.next() and it turns out that it is the complete Array of Strings which is "mapping" and "data". But I want to traverse and check first for "mapping" and then for "data". Now, I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: comapre with `fileName.equals("mapping")` and not with `==`. `fileName` must be initialized with `String fileName= iter.next()` as the first line of the `while` loop